# Incorrect number of columns while exporting hive table to csv

Tags: csv, hive

I have a hive table in which there is a row that has field such as *"Some data, some other data"*

Basically, there is a comma in the data.

But when I export the table containing this data to csv, it treats ***Some Data*** as one column and ***some other*** data as another column. 
So for that record everything is shifted by 1 column.

For example, in hive data is like :

```
 col_name_1               col_name_2         col_name_3
 some data,some other       myname          mylastname
```

but after export in csv the state is :

```
col_name_1    col_name_2         col_name_3       extra_not_required_col
  some data   some other data     myname          mylastname
```

So the data get corrupted in this fashion.
The code I am using toexport table to csv is :

```
hive -e "set hive.cli.print.header=true;use colorado;select * from $name;" | sed 's/[\t]/,/g' >>intermediate_table.csv
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you add double quotes around the commas in the data it should solve this issue when  your CSV reader reads the file.  You can replace it using the following in hive.

```
select regexp_replace(colname_1,'\\,','","') as colname_1_transformed from table;
```

Your data will then look like this which again a CSV reader should be able to handle:

some data","some other